# Set IP address of a network interface useing c# and .Net API without WMI

Tags: c#, .net, networking, ip, wmi

I'm a newcomer on .Net and c# programming.
I'm trying to perform a small program to set up in a few clics the IP address of my local network card. (What I want to achieve is going faster than through the windows configuration menus)
So I've made a little research and I found several nice examples that fits my needs.
Anyway, I've realised that I can get a network device IP config via .Net namespaces (System.Net.Networkinformation...) but I can't set a new one (I mean, this API is full of getters but no setters) so, as far as I googled, to set an IP I must perform WMI calls.
My question is if there is a method to do it via .Net (I didn't found it by de moment).
Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you search 'c# WMI class'? [C# WMI Tutorial](https://nathondalton.wordpress.com/2015/02/03/c-wmi-tutorial/)

Comment: Not sure what do you mean with *via .Net*. `System.Management` is part of the framework. If you don't like WMI, there's [IPHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/_iphlp/), if you prefere API calls, or [netsh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-contexts), it you like the command line console-style better.

Comment: Can you post what code you have already?

Comment: Any reason you can't use WMI?

Comment: It is common to use PowerShell these days which you can easily call from C#.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ORMi](https://github.com/nicoriff/ORMi) library as it is a WMI wrapper that makes WMI access simpler.

1) Define your class:

```
[WMIClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration")]
public class NetworkAdapterConfiguration
{
    public int Index { get; set; } //YOU MUST SET THIS AS IT IS THE CIM_KEY OF THE CLASS
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public uint IPConnectionMetric { get; set; }

    public UInt32 InterfaceIndex { get; set; }

    public string WINSScopeID { get; set; }

    public bool SetStatic(string ip, string netmask)
    {
        int retVal = WMIMethod.ExecuteMethod(this, new { IPAddress = new string[] { ip }, SubnetMask = new string[] { netmask } });

        if (retVal != 0)
            Console.WriteLine($"Failed to set network settings with error code {retVal}");

        return retVal == 0;
    }
}
```

2) Use:

```
        WMIHelper helper = new WMIHelper("root\\CimV2");

        NetworkAdapterConfiguration networkInterface = helper.Query<NetworkAdapterConfiguration>().ToList()
            .Where(n => n.Description == "Intel(R) Ethernet Connection").SingleOrDefault();

        networkInterface.SetStatic("192.168.0.35", "255.255.255.0");
```

Comment: thanks for the code sample! Running on windows 10, SetStatic seems to be replaced with EnableStatic and instead of returning int, returns an object with ReturnValue property instead